# Passing image as a parameter jasperreports

Tags: java

I try to pass image to ireports as parameter logo but when report appears it shows a string definition of the image instead of the logo.

In ireports i created the parameter logo and made its expression as object and dragged image on it from pallete. The image i made its expression to image

```
private void generateRptForm(String sql, String reportloader) {
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    Connection connect = null;
    try {
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + "school", user, password);
        pstmt = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT image FROM picture WHERE id = 1");
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        InputStream imageStream = null;
        BufferedImage image = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            imageStream = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
            image = ImageIO.read(imageStream);
        }
        System.out.println("image..." + image);
        connect.close();
        connect.close();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + "school", user, password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(reportloader);
        String sqltrans = sql;
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sqltrans);
        jd.setQuery(newQuery);
        // Get data from registration table

        String[] split = null;
        String schname = this.getTitle();
        split = schname.split("\\[");
        schname = split[1];
        split = schname.split("\\]");
        String[] regdetails = dbutils.checker.regdetails(split[0]);

        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        param.put("schoolname", regdetails[0]);
        param.put("address", regdetails[3]);
        param.put("zipcode", regdetails[4]);
        param.put("telephone", regdetails[5]);
        param.put("location", regdetails[1]);
        param.put("country", regdetails[2]);
        param.put("email", regdetails[6]);

        param.put("logo", image);

        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, param, conn);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: An irrelevant note: You do not need to open two connections to the DB,  using the first for the second query as well is perfectly OK and better performing.

Comment: And a relevant question: How are you using the image in the `jrxml` file? Can you post the relevant part?

Comment: @ Nikos Paraskevopoulos, 1.could you show/explain to me how you should pass an image as a parameter to a .jrxml file. 2.How do i format the jrxml file so that the image is shown. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are passing the image is OK. Use it in the `jrxml` as:

```
<image>
    <reportElement ... />
    <imageExpression class="java.awt.Image"><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

I.e. make sure the expression class is `java.awt.Image` and the expression itself points to the correct parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try below and create a parameter of object type and set the expression field of image as `$P{Image}`

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(img).getImage);
parameter.put("Image", imageIcon.getImage());
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to @Nikos Paraskevopoulos answer, if you are using latest version of jasper, you can use the following:

```
String logoPath = "E:/logo.png";
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
param.put("logo", logoPath);
```

In JRXML file modify

```
<image onErrorType="Blank">
    <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="130" height="40" uuid="71aa5ef6-4718-4cee-8a4b-e696aa90dd05"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

This method works for me. I tried it just before posting it here. Just treat the logo path as string. Just make sure you added a Parameter as logo as java string in jasper studio.

Comment: This works fine on windows but as soon as you move the code to a docker platform you will hit issues.

Comment: Actually my code was tested on Oracle Os as well. You just need to make sure the path define based on OS. Maybe can set variable based on OS checking.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put Image icon in your report and set it's Image Expression to image parameter (in your case logo parameter)

see: https://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/inserting-images-from-database-into-jasper-reports/